# .NET assembly merge tool required

Tags: .net

Is there any such tool which can link assemblies together and remove unused types?

Comment: There's a number of related questions -- see e.g. [these SO search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+assembly+merge). (in addition to +1 for Madhur :)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried ILMerge

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx

Comment: No unused types removal there. Read question carefully.